# Popup windows like Internet Explorer Favorite Windows

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I may not be able to describe my requirement correctly, but I'll try my best. I want to develop a web application in ASP.Net with C#.

The requirement is exactly like the windows popup:

When a user clicks on favorite button in IE-7 or 8, It opens a floating window on the page.
When the user clicks away from that popup, the window will either disappear or hide. 
There is a pin button, which is in the right-side corner of that popup window. When a user clicks that pin, it will stick and whole explorer contain will shift to right.

I have no idea which control to use and how to proceed. So, anyone with any idea about this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question right but, I guess what you are looking for is called "modal window". You can build your own with some css and javascript. If you don't want to get your hands dirty, I would suggest you have a look at some jQuery plugins. The one I prefer is [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) but there are plenty more if you search google for it.. Also you may want to have a look at [this list](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/).

Comment: I tried "Modal Window" but it was not meet my requirement. It is not allowing me to edit the background contains. It is making disable. But I need exactly how the "Favorite" module is working in IE-7/8

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the bookmark popup window that appears when you click that favourite (star) icon in IE?

Or

The side frame that appears in the left?

Comment: Yes, I need exactly how the "Favorite" module is working in IE-7/8.